# Google Fonts API usage limits

Tags: css, webfonts, google-webfonts, google-font-api

I am researching the best way to use non-standard webfonts on a high-traffic site.

Really it comes down to whether we use a service such as Typekit / Google or serve the fonts ourselves.

The terms of use on Typekit are clear, but with Google I cannot find any information about:

- uptime
- how many times a day / month I can request the font

Does anyone have any information on this, or experience of using in on a site with a lot of traffic?  The terms of service just points you to Google's generic APIs Terms of Service.

In these terms it states:

> API Limitations
>
> Google may set limits on the number of API requests that you can make,
>   at its sole discretion. You agree to such limitations and will not
>   attempt to circumvent such limitations.

But this is very broad - there doesn't seem to be any indication of what the limitation is, other than it *may* be limited.

Comment: Another option is to download the fonts from Google Fonts and host them yourself.

Comment: I would say that if you need to ask, you should host the fonts.

Comment: Yeah good point.  I guess therefore you can't reliably use Google Font API for a business critical site.

Answer (score -1):

for a "***business critical site***" you can always use [typekit](http://typekit.com/) from adobe
as for the option to host the fonts yourself... read again the paragraph you cite above:

> You agree to such limitations and will not attempt to circumvent such
>   limitations.

Comment: You agree to such limitations and will not attempt to circumvent such limitations.

That's not circumventing their API limit, that's simply not using their API. The fonts on google fonts are all open sourced. https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#Any_Page_OK